# Number of Simple Paths in the Context of an Input-Output Model

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, economics

I am trying to understand a publication on structural path analysis in economics. It uses some concepts from graph theory with which I am unfamiliar - but even so, I must be confused about the combinatorics, because the numbers don't add up:

[The 1988 article](https://github.com/michaelweinold/MMHLCA/blob/main/literature/sonis_1988_article.pdf) describes an [input-output matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input%E2%80%93output_model) $\mathbf{A}$, where the columns and rows correspond sectors of an economy and the elements of the matrix $a_{ij}$ are trade volumes between sectors $i \rightarrow j$.

In the graph theory approach that is introduced, a vertex $i$ correspondes to an economic sector $i$ and the arc $i \rightarrow j$ corresponds to the trade volume between sectors. The authors then state:

> For example, in an $n\times n$ input-output matrix, the number $P$ of all possible elementary paths between two vertices $j$ and $i$ is equal to
>
> $$
> P=1+(n-2)+(n-2)(n-3)+\ldots+(n-2)(n-3) \ldots 2 \times 1=(n-2) ! \sum \frac{1}{k !}
> $$

By *elementary paths*, the authors mean [simple paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#simple_path), where vertices are unique. (I am guessing they forgot to define the range for the index $k$ here.)

> and consequently, the number $N$ of all elementary paths for all pairs of different vertices is equal to
>
> $$
> N=n!\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{k}
> $$
> In a simple $5x5$ input-output matrix, there are 600 pairs of different vertices and each pair is associated with ten elementary paths, thus yielding 6000 elementary paths.

Now for $n=5$, I get $N=200$, according to the above equation. According to the article, this should be 600?

Also, for a 5-element set of sectors of the economy $(a,b,c,d,e)$ the total number of combinations of vertices should be 25 ($(aa), (ab), (ba), \dots$)? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lots to be confused by here.

The formula $$N = n! \sum_{k=1}^{n-2} \frac1{k!}$$ should indeed give $N = 200$ and not $N = 6000$ when $n=5$. I think I can guess where the mistake is. The claim that there are $600$ pairs of different vertices would be correct if we had $n = 25$, rather than $n=5$, since $600 = 25 \cdot 24$. From there, saying that there are $P=10$ elementary paths joining each pair of vertices agrees with the earlier formula for $P$. If we correct the quantity $600$ to $5 \cdot 4 = 20$, then multiplying by $10$ gives $200$, agreeing with the formula as written above.

Separately, the formulas for $P$ and for $N$ are incorrect if summed for $1 \le k \le n-2$. (The formula for $P$ is merely ambiguous in the paper, since it does not include a range; the formula for $N$ is flat-out incorrect.) We should have $0 \le k \le n-2$, giving $$P = (n-2)! \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac1{k!} \qquad \text{and} \qquad N = n! \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac1{k!}.$$
The value of $k$ tells us how many vertices should be *left out* of the path. The $k=0$ term corresponds to the $(n-2)!$ paths between two fixed vertices that visit every other vertex; the $k=1$ term corresponds to the $(n-2)!$ paths between two fixed vertices that visit all but one vertex. So, the correct count when $n=5$ is that there are $5 \cdot 4 = 20$ pairs of different vertices, and between each pair of vertices there are $$P = 1 + 3 + 3\cdot 2 + 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 16$$ paths, for a total of $N = 320$ paths.

By way of illustration, here are the $16$ paths from $a$ to $b$ when the sectors are $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$:

\begin{array}{cccc}
 (a,b) & (a,c,b) & (a,c,d,b) & (a,c,d,e,b)\\
  & (a,d,b) & (a,c,e,b) & (a,c,e,d,b) \\
  & (a,e,b) & (a,d,c,b) & (a,d,c,e,b) \\
  & & (a,d,e,b) & (a,d,e,c,b) \\
  & & (a,e,c,b) & (a,e,c,d,b) \\
  & & (a,e,d,b) & (a,e,d,c,b)
\end{array}

Finally, there are only $20$ and not $25$ pairs, because we want the paths to start and end at different vertices: if the sectors are $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ then we include pairs of endpoints like $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$, but not $(a,a)$. If we want to count cycles, or paths that start and end at the same vertex, that's a different problem. We'd want to nail down some details before we count these: does the cycle of length $0$ that ends where it starts without going anywhere count? What about a cycle like $(a,b,a)$? Does $(a,b,c,a)$ count separately from $(b,c,a,b)$, even though they're going around the same circle in the same direction? Once we answer these questions, a similar counting strategy will work.

Comment: Thank you for this incredibly helpful elaboration! It is a shame that no correction to the original article was ever published - this seems like a significant oversight after all. Do you have any recommendations on a textbook chapter that I could reference for the formulas giving the number of simple paths in a directed acyclic graph like this one?

Comment: Well, this is not a directed acyclic graph - you see that some of the paths above go from $c$ to $d$ and others go from $d$ to $c$. This is the number of simple paths in an undirected complete graph. For the formulas, I would consider citing the OEIS: sequence https://oeis.org/A000522 for $P$ and sequence https://oeis.org/A038154 for $N$.