# Total Number of Walks in a Simple Path

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory

The number of simple paths of all possible lengths $1<l<(n-1)$ between all combinations of nodes in a graph of $n$ nodes [is:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4704603/)

$$N_p(n, l=[1,\dots,n-1]) = n! \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} \frac1{k!}$$

The number of walks (allowing for loops) of length $\omega$ between all combinations in a graph of $n$ nodes [is (cf. page 388)](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511626982):

$$N_w(n, \omega)=n^{\omega+1}$$

My understanding is that every simple path of length $l$ contains a number of walks $n_w(l,\omega)$. If, for every possible length $l$ of simple paths, I multiply the number of simple paths with the number of walks for that length should therefore add up to $N_w(n, \omega)=n^{\omega+1}$?

I would therefore like to find an equation for the number of possible walks of length $\omega$ between two nodes $(i,j$) in a graph of $n$ elements, allowing for loops $(i,i)$ with the following properties:

`In a graph of n nodes, the walk must start at node i, end at node j and visit every node at least once.`

For $n=3$ and $\omega=3$, I visualized some possiblities:

[image]

Comment: Where you say "a graph of $n$ elements", you should be saying "a *complete* graph of $n$ elements". In an arbitrary graph, not all nodes are connected to each other, so a path cannot always move directly between any two nodes. Your counts appear to assume all nodes are directly linked. That is a "complete" graph. Also, could you please clarify what you mean by a "walk" vs a "path"? I have no desire to pay $8 to see the behind the paywall to your linked paper to determine what terminology they use.